# loop through lines sharing a field in awk

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I'm trying to write an awk script that takes all lines sharing a common field (e.g., the first) and loops through them twice to make all possible combinations among them.

It's best explained with an example -- given the following input:

```
cat input.txt

A this
A text
B MORE
B THINGS
```

I want the script to build all possible combinations of lines starting with "A", and then with "B". So, this would be the output:

```
cat output.txt

A this A this
A text A this
A this A text
A text A text
B MORE B MORE
B THINGS B MORE
B MORE B THINGS
B THINGS B THINGS
```

(All possible combinations of "this" and "text" + combinations of "MORE" and "THINGS")

So far, I've got this:

```
awk '{pair[++c] = $0 } END {
    for ( i = 1; i <= c; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 1; j <= c; j++ ){
            print pair[j], pair[i]
        }
    }
}' input.txt > output.txt
```

But the output is:

```
A this A this
A text A this
B MORE A this
B THINGS A this
A this A text
A text A text
B MORE A text
B THINGS A text
A this B MORE
A text B MORE
B MORE B MORE
B THINGS B MORE
A this B THINGS
A text B THINGS
B MORE B THINGS
B THINGS B THINGS
```

(It does not take into account if the first field is "A" or "B", and just makes all the combinations.)

Any ideas?

I've thought of splitting the input file according to the first field and doing the double loop with each split file. But I need a solution that also works for very long files with lots of different values in the first field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for 2D arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk         
{ vals[$1][$0] }
END {
    for (key in vals) {
        for (val1 in vals[key]) {
            for (val2 in vals[key]) {
                print val1, val2
            }
        }
    }
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
A this A this
A this A text
A text A this
A text A text
B MORE B MORE
B MORE B THINGS
B THINGS B MORE
B THINGS B THINGS
```

or if your first column is always ordered you can do this with any awk and it'll use far less memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1!=prev { shuffle() }
{ vals[$0]; prev=$1 }
END { shuffle() }

function shuffle(       val1, val2) {
    for (val1 in vals) {
        for (val2 in vals) {
            print val1, val2
        }
    }
    split("",vals)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A this A this
A this A text
A text A this
A text A text
B MORE B MORE
B MORE B THINGS
B THINGS B MORE
B THINGS B THINGS
```

Comment: The first one works like a charm, thanks a lot! Yes, I was using gawk. The second solution also works, but I won't always have my files sorted. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid arrays:

```
cat input.txt| while read f1 fn; do
   awk '/^'$f1'/ {print "'$f1' '$fn' "$0 }' input.txt
done
```

EDIT: changed input-file to input.txt and added awk-less solution:

For each line awk is started, so this solution might be slower (you can test).
A solution without awk wil start one more program every loop:

```
cat input.txt| while read f1 fn; do
   grep "^$f1" input.txt | sed 's/^/'"${f1} ${fn}"'/'
done
```

Comment: I think I get your answer, but I'm not sure what each file (`input` and `file`) is. Are they both the same `input.txt` file I was referring to?

Comment: @XGrau Yes, you are right. Changed it and added another solution. I guess it will be very slow for long files but will not run out of memory.

Comment: Nice, both work perfectly. It's true they are slower but may do the trick for small problems. I'd vote up but don't have enough rep -- thanks anyway! @walter-a